# XML To Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Есть XML строка такого типа:

```
<Tabelle name="WWS_ARTIKEL">

<FeldBeschreibung>
<Feld type="String(12)">ARTIKELNR</Feld>
<Feld type="String(6)">ARTIKELGRP</Feld>
</FeldBeschreibung>

<Datensaetze>
<Datensatz>
<Feld name="ARTIKELNR">1000</Feld>
<Feld name="ARTIKELGRP">1</Feld>
</Datensatz>

<Datensatz>
<Feld name="ARTIKELNR">2000</Feld>
<Feld name="ARTIKELGRP">2</Feld>
</Datensatz>
</Datensaetze>

</Tabelle>
</StammDaten>
```

Вопрос: как правильно ее десериализовать в java object?

Создал классы Stammdaten, Tabelle, Datensatz, Feld. Stammdaten я делаю

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "StammDaten")
```

затем

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Datensaetze")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Datensatz")
private List<Datensatz> datensaetze;
```

и так далее иду вниз по иерархическому дереву

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам, может кому пригодится.

Моя ошибка была в том, что в самом начале XML есть заглавный тэг `<lcs:LandwehrStammDaten ...>`. Это и есть в иерархическом дереве самый высокий его член.

Создается класс `LandwehrStammDaten` как и все остальные, стоящие ниже по иерархии: `StammDaten, Tabelle, Datensatz, Feld`

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "LandwehrStammDaten")
public class LandwehrStammDaten implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "StammDaten")
    private StammDaten stammdaten;
//getters and setters
}
//класс Tabelle по аналогии

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StammDaten implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Tabelle")
    private Tabelle tabelle;
//getters adn setters
}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Datensatz implements Serializable{

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Datensatz")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Feld")
    private List<Feld> Feld;
//getters and setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Feld implements Serializable{

    private static List<Feld> instances = new ArrayList();

    public Feld() {
        instances.add(this);
    }

    public static List<Feld> getList(){
        return instances;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlText(value = true)
    private String value;
//getters and setters
}
```